# Could the intro banner not be displayed if already displayed in one tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notification-bar

About the orange "Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers — check out the FAQ!" banner:
When I'm not yet logged in and I open multiple links of SO as separate tabs, every tab has this banner on it. It's rather annoying, coz it's intrusive. Pretty much like advertisement pop-up's.

Would it be possible to write a script that does not display the banner if another tab of SO is already open?

Comment: Same thing happens when you earn a badge or a privilege.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We didn't do this *specifically*, we just removed that banner since the usage of it was incredibly low.

Comment: +1 for this. I always thought it was unnecessary. Fixed, animated top banners to the tune of "register to view links", "please read the FAQ", etc. are usually a warning sign to me.